# Can I use Go slice unpacking to streamline this permutation function?

Tags: go

I have written the following Go function that produces all permutations of a boolean list of any size. Playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/vfit4zPSoFe).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func permutations(m int) [][]bool {
    if m == 0 {
        panic("CRASH")
    }
    if m == 1 {
        return [][]bool{{true}, {false}}
    }

    retVal := [][]bool{}
    for _, x := range permutations(m - 1) {
        slice1 := []bool{true}
        slice2 := []bool{false}
        for _, y := range x {
            slice1 = append(slice1, y)
            slice2 = append(slice2, y)
        }
        retVal = append(retVal, slice1)
        retVal = append(retVal, slice2)
    }
    return retVal
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    m := permutations(3)
    fmt.Println("m = ", m)
}
```

Can I streamline this function by using slice unpacking? If so, how?

Comment: I think, the most straightforward way to do this would be to iterate over numbers between `0` to `2^N-1` and convert each number to a slice of bool corresponding to its binary form.

Comment: This looks like a complicated way to implement a counting function.

Comment: You may do `slice1 = append(slice1, x...); slice2 = append(slice2, x...)` instead of the inner loop.